# Extended Response Time with simple_salesforce Library's upsert method

Tags: bulk-api, python, upsert, simple-salesforce

Problem Statement:

I'm encountering prolonged response times exceeding 30 seconds while using the simple_salesforce library to perform upsert operations in batches using the bulk functionality. The upsert method seems to take an extended duration to process, affecting the overall performance of my application.

Code Sample:

```
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce
import requests
import json

USERNAME = 'xxx'
PASSWORD = 'yyy'
CLIENT_ID = 'zzzzzzzzz'
CLIENT_SECRET = 'a1b1c1'
token_url = ''

payload = {
        'grant_type': 'password',
        'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
        'client_secret': CLIENT_SECRET,
        'username': USERNAME,
        'password': PASSWORD
    }
try:
print('Invoking token endpoint')
r = requests.post(
    token_url,
    headers={"Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}, data=payload)

body = r.json()
token = body['access_token']
print("session Id:",token)

sf = Salesforce(instance_url=instance_url, session_id=token)   


data = "[{"id": "1de4f46gfdvznasdsa","name": "Test-1"},{"id": "1gfsdvznasdsw324a1","name": "Test-2"},{"id": "46gfdvznasdsa2eref23","name": "Test-3"}]"
response = sf.bulk.Account.upsert(data, 'Account')
print("Response= ",response)   
    

    
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    print("Error in request:", str(e))

except Exception as e:
    print('Error: ', str(e))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is normal behavior with the Bulk API. This API is asynchronous and intended for use loading large volumes of data.

Bulk API operations may have substantial latency. In the normal use case with hundreds of thousands or millions of records, this latency is not noticeable.

You should not use the Bulk API for small batches where this unpredictable latency compared unfavorably with the time required to create the records. Use the REST API instead for synchronous operation.

Comment: What criteria or specifications should we consider while determining whether to utilize the REST API or the Salesforce Bulk API for data operations? Are there specific volume thresholds or other indicators that signal when it's more advantageous to opt for one over the other?

Comment: There isn't a hard cutoff. I generally use 2,000 records but that's not fixed by any means.